# mysql join two different tables to list one result

Tags: mysql, union

I have two MySQL tables: 'invoice' and 'credit_memo'

I would like to combine them and list one result ordered by date.

invoice:
ID INT
date DATETIME
customer_id INT

credit_memo:
ID INT
date DATETIME
customer_id INT

My final attempt:

```
(SELECT ID AS invoice_number FROM invoice)
UNION
(SELECT ID AS credit_memo_number FROM credit_memo)
ORDER BY date
```

The problem is that both the invoice_number and credit_memo_number get put into the invoice_number variable.  So when I run the result it all looks like its coming from the 'invoice' table.

How can I determine which table each particular row is pulling from?

Thank you,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will approach it.

Both tables have customer ID so we can join them through that:

```
SELECT i.ID AS invoice_number,c.ID AS credit_memo_number 
FROM invoice i
JOIN credit_memo c ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
ORDER BY i.date ASC
```

This will select the invoice ID and the credit ID and order them by the Invoice date.

Comment: This doesn't look like what he's trying to do. If customer (lets say Joe) has two invoices (lets say invoice A and invoice B) for a particular date and two credit memos (lets say memo C and D), then you will end up with: (Joe, A, C), (Joe, B, C), (Joe, A, D), (Joe, B, D). I don't think he wants all of those repeats. The customer ID doesn't seem like a good join column there.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, t.table_name from invoice join information_schema.tables t on t.table_name='invoice'
union
select id, t.table_name from credit_memo join information_schema.tables t on t.table_name='credit_memo'
```